# Solution of a PDE Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega = \{(t, x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^3~|~t^2 - x^2 > 0\}$. I want to solve the following Cauchy problem
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
x \partial_t u + t \partial_x u - \partial_y u = u + y & \text{for } (t, x, y) \in \Omega\\
u(t, 0, y) = 1 - y &\text{for } (t, 0, y) \in \Omega
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
but I have no idea how to do this. Could one of you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+t\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=u+y \tag 1$$
Charpit-Lagrange syqtem of characteristic ODEs : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics
$$\frac{dt}{x}=\frac{dx}{t}=\frac{dy}{-1}=\frac{du}{u+y}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{x}=\frac{dx}{t}=\frac{dy}{-1}$

$\frac{dt}{x}=\frac{dx}{t}=\frac{dt+dx}{x+t}\quad\implies\quad \frac{d(t+x)}{t+x}+dy=0$
$$(t+x)e^y=c_1$$

A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{x}=\frac{dx}{t}=\frac{dy}{-1}$

$\frac{dt}{x}=\frac{dx}{t}=\frac{dt-dx}{x-t}\quad\implies\quad -\frac{d(t-x)}{t-x}+dy=0$
$$(t-x)e^{-y}=c_2$$

A third characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{-1}=\frac{du}{u+y}\quad\implies\quad\frac{du}{dy}+u=-y$
$$(u+y-1)e^y=c_3$$
The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicite equation $\Phi(c_1,c_2,c_3)=0$ is :
$$\Phi\big((t+x)e^y \:,\: (t-x)e^{-y}  \:,\: (u+y-1)e^y\big)=0$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of three variables.

Or equivalently on explicit form $c_3=F(c_1,c_2)$ :
$$(u+y-1)e^y=F\big((t+x)e^y \:,\: (t-x)e^{-y} \big)$$
$$\boxed{u(t,x,y)=-y+1+e^{-y}F\big((t+x)e^y \:,\: (t-x)e^{-y} \big)} \tag 2$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables (To be determined according to the condition $u(t,0,y)=1-y$ ).

Condition : $$u(t,0,y)=1-y=-y+1+e^{-y}F\big(t\,e^y \:,\: t\,e^{-y} \big)$$

This is possible only if $F=0$. Thus the particular solution which satisfies the condition is :
$$u(t,x,y)=-y+1$$
This trivial solution could have been found at first by inspection of the PDE without all the above calculus.

IN ADDITION : CHECKING OF THE GENERAL SOLUTION $(2)$ :

$$u(t,x,y)=-y+1+e^{-y}F(X,Y)\quad 
\begin{cases}
X=(t+x)e^y \\
Y=(t-x)e^{-y} 
\end{cases}$$ 
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=e^{-y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial t}+e^{-y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial t}=
\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}+e^{-2y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=e^{-y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}+e^{-y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}=
\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}-e^{-2y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-1-e^{-y}F+e^{-y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial y}+e^{-y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial y}=
-1-e^{-y}F+(t+x)\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}-(t-x)e^{-2y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}$

$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+t\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=$$
$=x\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}+e^{-2y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\right)
+t\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}-e^{-2y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\right)
-\left(-1-e^{-y}F+(t+x)\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}-(t-x)e^{-2y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\right)$

After simplification : 
$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+t\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=1+e^{-y}F=1+(u+y-1)=u+y$$
This is the equation $(1)$. Thus $(2)$ is the solution of the PDE $(1)$.